# Sort MySQL result set using comparison between 2 columns of same value type

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table containing `last_updated_1` and `last_updated_2` columns, used respectively for text and images update time on a post.

I wish I could get a result set of 10 rows based on all time last updated records contained in the 2 columns, ex. row 1 = `last_updated_1` record, row 2 = `last_updated_2` record, row 3 = `last_updated_1` record, etc.

How could I compare inside a MySQL query the both columns values, to get unique & mixed result set ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, this should do it:

```
SELECT D.val, D.tstamp
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT val AS val, last_updated_1 AS tstamp
        FROM table_1
        ORDER BY tstamp
        LIMIT 50
    )

    UNION

    (
        SELECT val AS val, last_updated_2 AS tstamp
        FROM table_2
        ORDER BY tstamp
        LIMIT 50
    )
) AS D
ORDER BY D.tstamp
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for anwser. Columns are in the same table, not in 2 tables; these record update time for 1)text, 2)image updates on one same post.

The script you suggest basically works but get duplicate results if difference between the 2 update values is short, and adding DISTINCT does not change a thing.

I would like to select smth like (if col1 has more recent datetime than col2, than select col1 datetime value).

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT D.id ...
FROM (( SELECT id, ...) UNION (SELECT id, ...)) AS D ...